# Array to Strong Conversion Error?

Tags: php

For my semester project I am trying to read a file and extract data from it to insert into a database. However, I am getting an "Array to String Conversion" error. I've spent a while trying to figure this out, but I can't figure out what specifically is causing it. Any help will be greatly appreciated!

The error occurs on this line:

```
$mydb->query("INSERT INTO account(`UserID`, `Role`, `CaptureID`, `FirstName`, `LastName`, `EmailAddress`, `PhoneNumber`) VALUES($newuserid, 2, $capid, '$fname', '$lname', '$email', '$phone');");
```

The code:

```
<?php
require_once("db".DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR."db.php");
global $mydb;

class DataExtractor{
    function extract($file, $capid){
        global $mydb;
        $phone = "";
        $email = "";
        $fname = "";
        $lname = "";

        $handle = fopen($file, "r");
        if ($handle) {
            while (($line = fgets($handle)) !== false) {
                if(preg_match('/^(\d[\s-]?)?[\(\[\s-]{0,2}?\d{3}[\)\]\s-]{0,2}?\d{3}[\s-]?\d{4}$/i',$line, $matches)){
                    $phone = $matches[0];
                }

                if (preg_match("/[a-z\d._%+-]+@[a-z\d.-]+\.[a-z]{2,4}\b/i", $line, $email)){
                    $email = $email[0];
                }

                $name = $this->search($line);
                $fname = $name[0];
                $lname = $name[1];

                /*if (isset($phone) && isset($email) && isset($fname) && isset($lname)){ //leave out for now
                    break;
                }*/
            }

            $newuserid = md5(uniqid(rand(), true));
            $actid = md5(uniqid(rand(), true));
            $mydb->query("INSERT INTO account(`UserID`, `Role`, `CaptureID`, `FirstName`, `LastName`, `EmailAddress`, `PhoneNumber`) VALUES($newuserid, 2, $capid, '$fname', '$lname', '$email', '$phone');"); //ERROR
            $mydb->query("INSERT INTO activation(`ActivationID`, `UserID`, `Activated`) VALUES($actid, $newuserid, 0);");
            fclose($handle);
        } else {
            // error opening the file.
        } 
    }

    function search($str){
        require "utils".DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR."dictionary-first-names.php";
        $arr = explode(" ", $str);

        for ($i = 0; $i < sizeof($str); $i++){
            if (in_array($arr[$i], $dict)){
                return array($arr[$i], $arr[$i+1]);
            }
        }
    }
}
$dataextract = new DataExtractor();?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is at `$email`. If the regex fails to match, the `$email` variable will contain an array, instead of a string, as you expect. That's why the error occurred.

Moreover, in the same line and the line after, the variables `$newuserid` and `$actid` should be surrounded with quotes, as the result generated by `md5()` function is a string.